# "You have really nice hair" or "Your hair is really nice"?

Tags: sentence-structure

What is a more common and natural compliment, "Your something is..." or "You have..."? For example "You have really nice hair" or "Your hair is really nice"?
The issue is that I sent a message to girl "Your hair is really nice" and she corrected me having sent me "You have really nice hair".
I am just confused.

Comment: I'd go with her on this! Simply because I don't like using *is* with *hair!*. *You have really nice hair* solves the purpose and soothes my eyes! :)

Comment: As a matter of language either should be OK, but in reality “You have really nice hair” is better because you are complimenting her for taking good care of her hair.

Comment: You could have just replied: "Why thank you very much!  I, also, believe my hair is one of my finer attributes. ;-)"  This would show her you're clever and intentionally misunderstanding her intended *correction* as a compliment to yourself.  Oh, then accuse her of being a brat! Girls.  smh.

Answer (score 4):

Tell her whatever she wants to hear.

In practical purposes, you are complimenting either the entire person:

***You*** have really nice hair.

Or you are complimenting an attribute:

***Your hair*** is really nice.

There are contexts when one or the other will serve you better.